# Visualizing images from an array

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use a loop in order to display images that are inside of an array. The code I am using is producing blocks of text, yet I need it to produce the images from the links included in the text and not the text itself. Im not sure if the loop should be placing this information into a img src=" " or a div or something totally different. Either way the hope is to loop through the array, and rather than returning blocks of text return the image and just use the text as a description for said image. In the end their should be 12 images with a description under them, not 12 blocks of text. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

```js
var xmlHttp = createHttpRequestObj();
function createHttpRequestObj() {
  // Code for handling obsolete browsers omitted for brevity
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function sendHttpRequest(sURL) {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", sURL, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      sendHttpRequest(sURL);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
      handleResponseData(xmlResponse);
    }
  }
}

sendHttpRequest("https://geopingyin.com/gis/Locations.php");

function handleResponseData(JSONData) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSONData);
  var output = "";
  for (i in obj.Locations) {
    output += obj.Locations[i].Name + "<br>" + obj.Locations[i].Caption + "<br>" + obj.Locations[i].URL + "<br>" + obj.Locations[i].Thumb_URL +"<br>" + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = output
}
```

```html
<h2>Location List</h2>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: you need to add image objects with the url as the src, you are just adding the the url as text

Comment: Could you expound on this more for me? I am unable to change the php file that I am gathering my URLs from. When i use my loop to bring in the information from the php file it brings it all in as text and I am not sure how to bring the URLs in as images instead.

Comment: [Why is using "for...in" with array iteration a bad idea?](//stackoverflow.com/q/500504)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `<img>` elements from the data you received and append them to the DOM:

```
function handleResponseData(JSONData) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSONData);
  var parent = document.getElementById("results");
  for (var i in obj.Locations) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = obj.Locations[i].URL;
    img.setAttribute("title", obj.Locations[i].Name);
    parent.appendChild(img);

    var desc = document.createElement("div");
    desc.textContent = obj.Locations[i].Caption;
    parent.appendChild(desc);
  }
}
```

Once you grasped this it could be further augmented: when creating elements inside a loop it's usually better to append them to a [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and then append the fragment to the DOM (e.g. the "parent" element with `results` id) when the loop is finished instead of appending each separate element to the DOM as each such operation causes [reflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/reflow) - preventing it can speed up the process with large datasets:

```
  //var parent = document.getElementById("results");
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (...) {
    // ...
    fragment.appendChild(img);
  }
  document.getElementById("results").appendChild(fragment);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your code example and explanation, I found them both to be very useful!

Answer (score 0):

While Tomas is right, you need to put an image tag with src pointing to the url, I'm going to recommend a different approach.

Sperate your concerns as much as possible. You don't really want to go and change javascript if you want to change your layout/design. Keep that in your html.

```js
var xmlHttp = createHttpRequestObj();
function createHttpRequestObj() {
  // Code for handling obsolete browsers omitted for brevity
  return new XMLHttpRequest();
}

function sendHttpRequest(sURL) {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 0 || xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    xmlHttp.open("GET", sURL, true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
    xmlHttp.send();
  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {
      sendHttpRequest(sURL);
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
  if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
    if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
      xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseText;
      handleResponseData(xmlResponse);
    }
  }
}

sendHttpRequest("https://geopingyin.com/gis/Locations.php");

function handleResponseData(JSONData) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(JSONData);
  var output = "";
  
  //Set Up the template
  var s = document.getElementById("resultTemplate").innerHTML.trim();
  var holder = document.createElement('div');
  holder.innerHTML = s;
  var boxTemplate = holder.childNodes;
  
  for (i in obj.Locations) {
    //Clone Template    
    var newItem = boxTemplate[0].cloneNode(true);
    //Populate Template Elements
    newItem.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = obj.Locations[i].Name;
    newItem.querySelector(".caption").innerHTML = obj.Locations[i].Caption;
    newItem.querySelector(".image>a").href = obj.Locations[i].URL;
    newItem.querySelector(".image>a>img").src = obj.Locations[i].Thumb_URL;    
    //Add to the doc
    document.getElementById("results").appendChild(newItem);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<h2>Location List</h2>
<ul id="results"></ul>
<!-- Ideally we'd use the new <template> tag here but IE support is no good -->
<script type="text/template" id="resultTemplate">
  <li>
    <h1 class="name"></h1>
    <p class="caption">
    <div class="image">
      <a href=""><img src=""></a>
    </div>
  </li>
</script>
```